# Pentaho PDI Data Integration (Spoon) v5.2 has no transaction tab available in Job

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) version 5.2 on Mac OSX
I would like to create transaction for the 3 transformation in my job.

I follow this manual https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0L0/0Y0/0H0

But there is no Transaction or Miscellaneous Tab in the Job Setting (but it does has in Transformation setting)

Do you guys have any idea how to bring it?

Best Regards,

Comment: In my windows OS,  i am able to view the Transaction tab for Job. I am not sure about the issue. It might be some issue with your pentaho installation, which i am not sure about... Better raise a jira issue request regarding this ... link here http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.10+Job+Settings, that feature is only in Enterprise Edition. You should check your Pentaho version.